# how to use session in iphone programming?

Tags: iphone

I made an iphone story book application.
Suppose any user read story book and at half of the story book he/she close the apps.
when he/she want to read again this application at a time ask for continue or start again.
This is possible by using session but i don't know how to use session in iphone sdk.
So, please help me about this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it more or less manually. One way to do it is to write to `NSUserDefaults` in your `ApplicationWillTerminate:` method of your app delegate, and then to load in `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching:`